# List file names based on a filename pattern and file content?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ftp, grep

How can I use grep command to search `file name` based on a wild card `"LMN2011*"`  listing all files with this as beginning?

I want to add another check on those file content.

If `file content` has some thing like

```
LMN20113456
```

Can I use `grep` for this?

```
grep -ls "LMN2011*"   "LMN20113456"
```

What is the proper way to search the file names and its contents using shell commands?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Grep DOES NOT use "wildcards" for search – that's shell globbing, like *.jpg.
Grep uses "regular expressions" for pattern matching. While in the shell '*' means "anything", in grep it means "match the previous item zero or more times".

More information and examples here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

To answer of your question - you can find files matching some pattern with grep:

```
find /somedir -type f -print | grep 'LMN2011' # that will show files whose names contain LMN2011
```

Then you can search their content (case insensitive):

```
find /somedir -type f -print | grep -i 'LMN2011' | xargs grep -i 'LMN20113456'
```

If the paths can contain spaces, you should use the "zero end" feature:

```
find /somedir -type f -print0 | grep -iz 'LMN2011' | xargs -0 grep -i 'LMN20113456'
```

Comment: How can i write the result filenames to a text file in the server

Comment: -print is not required, it is always set to true.

Answer (score 37):

It can be done without `find` as well by using grep's `"--include"` option.

grep man page says:

```
--include=GLOB
Search only files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard matching as described under --exclude).
```

So to do a recursive search for a string in a file matching a specific pattern, it will look something like this:

```
grep -r --include=<pattern> <string> <directory>
```

For example, to recursively search for string "mytarget" in all Makefiles:

```
grep -r --include="Makefile" "mytarget" ./
```

Or to search in all files starting with "Make" in filename:

```
grep -r --include="Make*" "mytarget" ./
```

Comment: it would be nice to know, "how it can be done without find", really, only to share point of view

Answer (score 8):

```
grep LMN20113456 LMN2011*
```

or if you want to search recursively through subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -name 'LMN2011*' -exec grep LMN20113456 {} \;
```

Comment: How can i write the result filenames to a text file in the server

Comment: Use grep -l to list matched filenames instead of matched lines and then redirect the output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

> find /folder -type f -mtime -90 | grep -E
>   "(.txt|.php|.inc|.root|.gif)" | xargs ls -l  >
>   WWWlastActivity.log

Answer (score 0):

Assume `LMN2011*` files are inside `/home/me` but skipping anything in `/home/me/temp` or below:

```
find /home/me -name 'LMN2011*' -not -path "/home/me/temp/*" -print | xargs grep 'LMN20113456'
```